# How can i run an .exe file with Assembly class

Tags: c#, class, .net-assembly

I want to run my exe file with Assembly class. Here is my codes

```
Assembly as = Assembly.LoadFile("path");
as.EntryPoint.Invoke(null,null);
```

Error:

> Parameter count mismatch.

Comment: I've edited your question to match my answer :)... Please check if the error you are getting with your code is the one I've put in your question. Feel free to revert/updated.

Answer (score 3):

If it is native exe - use [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), if it is managed (i.e. create with C#) you need to load assembly and than call `Main` via reflection.

Native exe:

```
  Process.Start("IExplore.exe");
```

It looks like you have managed assembly and you've already know `Main` entrypoint (via [Assembly.EntryPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.entrypoint%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property). You need to makes sure it is not `null` (unlikely) and pass correct arguments.

`Main` signatures are `static void Main(string[] args)` or `static int Main(string[] args)` or `static void Main()`  so you need to pass `null` for instance in `Invoke` and correct number of arguments. If `Main` takes no parameters - use `new object[0]` for second parameter, otherwise construct string array with parameters and than wrap it in `new object[]{args}`.

Sample for case where `Main` takes arguments but does not do anything with them:

```
Assembly as = Assembly.LoadFile(@"c:\temp\my.exe");   
as.EntryPoint.Invoke(null, new object[]{new string[0]});
```

Comment: I'm sorry i dont understand thesee codes. I know how i can run exe file with process.start but i want to do this with Assembly class, so may you give me complete code for that?

Comment: @user3552431 - what  exactly you don't understand? your sample was almost correct... I've edited answer to add your first line from your sample  (assuming "path" is valid path to an executable like `@"c:\temp\my.exe"`, not just literal `"path"` value).

Comment: `static void Main()` is also a valid signature for `Main`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load an executable .NET assembly into your own process use [`AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sxx9f4c2.aspx):

```
int exitCode = AppDomain.Current.ExecuteAssembly("path");
```

There is also `ExecuteAssemblyByName` if you have the assembly name instead of the path.